# Iterating over object instances of a given class in Python and sys.getrefcount

Tags: python

Given a class that keeps a registry of its Objects

```
import sys


class TheClass(object):
    """
    the _registry hold references to all instances of TheClass
    it updates when new instance created or deleted
    """

    _registry = {}

    @staticmethod
    def new(name):
        if name in TheClass._registry:
            return TheClass._registry[name]
        return TheClass(name)

    @staticmethod
    def keys():
        return list(TheClass._registry.keys())

    @staticmethod
    def update():
        TheClass._registry = {name: inst for name, inst in TheClass._registry.items()
                              if sys.getrefcount(inst) > 4}

    def __init__(self, name):

        self._registry[name] = self
        self.name = name
```

it is working well

```
# create 3 instances
inst1 = TheClass.new(1)
inst2 = TheClass.new(2)
inst2.reference = TheClass.new(3)

print(TheClass.keys())
# >>> [1, 2, 3]

# delete reference to 1 instance
# 3 instances are still in _registry
inst2.reference = None
print(TheClass.keys())
# >>> [1, 2, 3]

# update the _registry
# delete a reference to inst3  from _registry
TheClass.update()
print(TheClass.keys())
# >>> [1, 2]
```

I need to update the _registry when a instance not referenced anymore, but the _registry is referencing object by itself, I use **sys.getrefcount** for detection of instances with only one reference from the _reference.

I expect only one reference, but there are 4

```
TheClass._registry = {name: inst for name, inst in TheClass._registry.items()
                              if sys.getrefcount(inst) > 4}
```

**Questions**:

1. Why 4? Is it Python version/platform dependent?
2. Is there more elegant solution?

Comment: Side note: the way you've written `new` will always create a new instance and replace the old one in the registry. It never returns an old instance.

Comment: Not agree:    inst1 = TheClass.new(1);
inst2 = TheClass.new(1) # inst1 and inst2 are referenced to same object.

Comment: Check `inst1 is inst2`

Comment: @АлександрИванов Alex Hall is correct, Python function calls are eager so `Registry.get(name, TheClass(name))` is executed as `_v = TheClass(name); Registry.get(name, _v)`, which first creates a new instance and updates the registry, then looks into it (finding the instance it has just created). `Registry.get(name) or TheClass(name)` is probably closer to what you want there, as `or` will shortcut.

Comment: Yes, there is my bug. I update the new(), but it not related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Why 4? Is it Python version/platform dependent?

- the registry has one
- the local variable in the dictionary comprehension is one
- the argument inside `getrefcount` is one

The `items` iterator likely has the last one

```py
for k in d:
    print(sys.getrefcount(d[k])) # 2 (d and getrefcount)
for k in d:
    v = d[k]
    print(sys.getrefcount(v)) # 3 (d, v and getrefcount)
for v in d.values():
    print(sys.getrefcount(v)) # 3 (d, dict_valueiterator, and getrefcount)
for k, v in d.items():
    print(sys.getrefcount(v)) # 4 (d, dict_itemiterator, v, and getrefcount)
```

You can use `gc.get_referrers` to enumerate them though the output tends to be gnarly.

> Is there more elegant solution?

[WeakValueDictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary) maps an arbitrary key to a weakref, and removes the entry when the weakref is collected.

Comment: Thank you very much, WeakValueDictionary is what I need.